# IEnumerable and Lazy loading

Tags: c#, .net, collections, ienumerable, iqueryable

I have below model -

```
public class Student
{
     public int StudentID { get; set; }
     public string StudentName { get; set; }
     public Nullable<int> StandardId { get; set; }

     public virtual Standard Standard { get; set; }
}  

public class Standard
{      
     public int StandardId { get; set; }
     public string StandardName { get; set; }

     public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

The relationship is -> One Standard can have multiple Students.
When below code is executed using IEnumerable it performs lazy loading, as can be seen from logs below

Code-

```
using (var ctx = new SchoolDBEntities())
{
  ctx.Database.Log = Logger.Log;

  IEnumerable<Student> studList = ctx.Students;
  foreach(Student std in studList)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("Student Name = " + std.StudentName);

     //Loads Student standard for particular Student only (separate SQL query)
     Standard standard = std.Standard;
     Console.WriteLine("Standard Name = " + standard.StandardName);
  }
}
```

Logs-
[image: Logs-]

It can be seen from the logs that the "Standard" table data is fetched when it was required. 
Then why it is said that IEnumerable does not support Laze Loading and IQueryable does?

When I run the code using IQueryable in place of IEnumerable it shows the same logs.
I didn't find any example explaining the point how IEnumerable does not support Lazy Loading.

Comment: Both `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable` have deferred execution - in other words lazy loading.

Comment: @Enigmativity - Can you provide a link or source explaining that both support lazy loading.

Comment: @Enigmativity Both of them support deferred execution, none of them support lazy loading. EF proxy classes support lazy loading

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto So I can say that Lazy loading is because of `std.Standard` in the code and IEnumerable and IQueryable has nothing to do with it

Comment: No, you can't, because `IQueryable` is what allows EF to generate queries.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - I was using the term "lazy loading" as I felt that the OP thought that is what deferred execution was.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Then why it is said that IEnumerable does not support Laze Loading

Lazy loading is an ORM concept (Entity Framework in your case).
You may consider it as an implementation detail.

Neither `IEnumerable<T>`, nor `IQueryable<T>` support lazy loading themselves.

```
IEnumerable<Student> studList = ctx.Students;
```

Regardless of *variable* type (`IEnumerable<Student>`), referenced *object type* will be `DbSet<Student>`, which implements `IQueryable<Student>`.

`DbSet<T>` uses EF infrastructure to materialize objects. Lazy loading is implemented by proxy types, generated by EF object materializer. This is not `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>` feature.

P.S.

As said above, deferred execution != lazy loading.

`IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>` support deferred execution. For `IQueryable<T>` this means, that query will be executed, and object will be materialized only when you will start to enumerate query results.

But this is not lazy loading. `Student.Standard` will be loaded, when you'll call property getter. This *is* lazy loading. As you can see, it has noting to do with `IQueryable<T>`: you don't need `IQueryable<T>` to call property getter.

Comment: Thanks for the point that DbSet implements IQueryable internally, that clears the question that when using Entity Framework IEnumerable will also support Lazy loading. Is there any scenario where it can be demonstrated that IEnumerable doesn;t support Lazy loading Or can we say that both supports lazy loading.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's incorrect to say so, because these interfaces have nothing about lazy loading. Lazy loading is supported by EF infrastructure.

Comment: "which implements IQueryable<Student> to support lazy loading." - but how whatever collection implements related to EF lazy loading?

Answer (score 5):

This is about runtime vs. compile time types, and also the collection vs. the objects it contains.

When you perform a query can assign to an `IEnumerable<T>` variable it is still a `IQueryable<T>` underneath.

However as soon as you use a `IEnumerable<T>` method on it the collection will not longer be a queryable. Eg. calling `ToArray` or `ToList`.

The major impact of this is that further operations (eg. `Where` for filtering) will happen in memory, rather than changing the query.

***However*** this has nothing to do with lazy properties for EF associations (the `std.Standard` in your code) which is done on the individual object in the collection, not the collection.

So if you have

```
var qry = /* something to create an IQueryable<T> from your DbContent */

foreach (var x in qry) {
  // qry has been enumerated: so SQL has been generated and executed
}

qry = qry.Where(some-condition);

foreach (var x in qry) {
  // qry has been enumerated: SQL with extra condition applied is run
}    

var e = qry.ToList();

// Anything done to e is done in memory, there will be no new
// SQL sent to the DB for the collection/

var f = e.First();
// But, as Standard is a lazy property this will generated a query.
x = e.Standard.SomeProperty;
```

Comment: So, since the Standard property is defined as virtual in the code, it is lazily loaded, and IEnumerable or IQueryable will execute in same manner in this case ?

Comment: @JitendraPanchal No, you are using `IQueryable` in both cases

Answer (score -1):

It's just my guess, if I am wrong, I would be happy to get corrected.

What I know, `IQueryable` inherits from `IEnumerable`. The underlaying type when working with your DB context should be `IQueryable` - that also enables the lazy loading.

You can always convert `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable` (and vice-versa through extension methods). What is the plus of `IQueryable` is that LL - you can perform operations/filtering on the query without executing it immediately. That's pretty useful when working with large amount of data.

Comment: You either "perform" and operation or you don't. You can't perform an operation and have it execute later. Nevertheless, both `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable` have deferred execution. There is no distinction on that point.